# Clean slate board

Tags: cleaning, slate

I have a slate board taken from an old pool table that I want to use as chalkboard.  There are some markings, maybe made with permanent markers, which I'd like to remove.  I tried just wiping them off but they don't come off.  How can I remove them without damaging the board?

Answer (score 1):

If permanent marker, alcohol is the usual solvent.

Comment: Removed the markers but left stains on the slate.  Maybe sanding the slate is better?  Any advice for that?